# how do I read just specific key values and perform action from multile dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

What I am trying to do is, read a csv and pass the values from csv into a weather api (https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=06611&appid=a6962678a5cba51e8db12b46bc87a86), and write the results to a new csv file. i am achieving this as follows:

csv data looks as below:

```
Zip, start, end
-----------------
33018, , 
75001, ,
54590, ,
84740, ,
82310, ,
```

'''

```
#output as dictionaries for each row
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("ziplist.csv"))
for row in input_file:
    print(row)
```

'''

output is dictionaries:

```
{'zip': '33018', 'start': '', 'end': ''}
{'zip': '75001', 'start': '', 'end': ''}
{'zip': '54590', 'start': '', 'end': ''}
{'zip': '84740', 'start': '', 'end': ''}
{'zip': '82310', 'start': '', 'end': ''}
```

Now, I want to read each value of the key, zip and perform an action to retrieve sunrise and sunset, and then write the results to a specific column in a new csv. So, my new csv should look like this:

```
Zip, start, end
-----------------
33018, 6:53:44 , 19:53:44
75001, 5:45:30 , 18:40:33
54590, 6:53:44 , 19:53:44
84740, 6:53:44 , 19:53:44
```

The function i created to retrieve sunrise and sunset values is:

'''
    import requests,json, datetime

```
#Enter your API key here
api_key = "a6962678a5cba51e8db12b46bc87a867"

#base_url variable to store url
base_url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"

#Give zipcode
zipcode=input("Enter Zipcode: ")

# complete_url variable to store 
# complete url address 
complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + zipcode

# get method of requests module 
# return response object 
response = requests.get(complete_url)

# json method of response object  
# convert json format data into 
# python format data 
data = response.json()
#print(data)

def time_converter(time):
    converted_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int(time)
    ).strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
    return converted_time

# Now data contains list of nested dictionaries 
# Check the value of "cod" key is equal to 
# "404", means city is found otherwise, 
# city is not found
def getDayLight(zipcode):
    d = dict();
    if data['cod'] != "404": 
        sunrise = time_converter(data['sys']['sunrise'])
        sunset = time_converter(data['sys']['sunset'])
        d['Status'] = "OK"
        d['Rise'] = sunrise
        d['Set'] = sunset
        return d
    elif data['cod'] != "200": 
        d['Status'] = "None"
        return d
        #print(" City Not Found ")
    else:
        d['Status'] = "Error"
        return d

print(getDayLight(zipcode))
print('\n')
print("-------------")
print(data)

#Unit tests
print(getDayLight(12203))
print(getDayLight(98052))
print(getDayLight(000))
print(getDayLight('$#@'))
print(getDayLight('rew'))
```

'''

I am struggling how to iterate through the dictionaries to perform the action to write into a new csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove spaces in your csv file. Like this:

```
zip,start,end
33018,,
75001,,
54590,,
84740,,
82310,,
```

You can read the csv file using pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
ziplist = pd.read_csv('ziplist.csv')
```

ziplist looks like this:

```
| Zip   | start | end |
|-------|-------|-----|
| 33018 | NaN   | NaN |
| 75001 | NaN   | NaN |
| 54590 | NaN   | NaN |
| 84740 | NaN   | NaN |
| 82310 | NaN   | NaN |
```

get results:

```
results = ziplist.Zip.apply(getDayLight)
all_rise = results.apply(lambda x: x['Rise'])
all_set = results.apply(lambda x: x['Set'])
```

assign the results you get to your dataframe named ziplist:

```py
ziplist['start'] = all_rise
ziplist['end'] = all_set
```

ziplist looks like this:

```
|   | Zip   | start       | end         |
|---|-------|-------------|-------------|
| 0 | 33018 | 08:30:46 AM | 08:59:43 PM |
| 1 | 75001 | 08:30:46 AM | 08:59:43 PM |
| 2 | 54590 | 08:30:46 AM | 08:59:43 PM |
| 3 | 84740 | 08:30:46 AM | 08:59:43 PM |
| 4 | 82310 | 08:30:46 AM | 08:59:43 PM |
```

Save your DataFrame as csv:

```py
ziplist.to_csv('results.csv')
```

Comment: can this be written without using pandas?